# Cakephp auth component with two models session

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, cookies, cakephp-2.0

I have two cakephp2 applications running on same database, but having different Auth tables and different $this->Auth->userModel values accordingly.
Authentication works well and users from one app can't log into other.

BUT.. as apps uses same CAKEPHP session cookie, this happens:
when user from app 'one' logs in, it can access any Auth protected action in app 'two'!

I will probably use different user roles and cookie names.
But still, why Auth component is ignoring Auth->userModel settings when checking the session? Is there a way to configure it to work right in this situation?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with this, but when AuthComponent stores user to the session, it uses `User` always no matter what the user models name actually is - its hard-coded.

Comment: Thats wrong @tigrang, at least for 2.0.

Comment: I swore I saw it hard-coded when I was looking at the source the other day - should have double checked, my bad.

Comment: See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers and afair it was also fixed in 1.3 years ago, it was in fact an issue - in the past. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If not configured otherwise, AuthComponent will write the authenticated user record to the `Auth.User` session key in CakePHP 2. [But it can be changed:](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component)

> **AuthComponent::sessionKey**
>
> The session key name where the record of the current user is stored. If unspecified, it will be "Auth.User".

(In CakePHP 1.3 [this was different](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/auth-component): `Auth.{$userModel name}`)

So, if your apps share a Session, which they do, if cookie name and `Security.salt` match, the logged in record will be shared.

There are two possibilities to solve this:

#### Separate the logins

Simply set a different `AuthComponent::sessionKey` for your two models. This will allow them to keep the logged in user separately

#### Separate the sessions

Configure different Cookie names and Salts for both apps, so their sessions cannot override each other. This is probably the cleaner solution, because it also covers the risk of other session keys being double-used.

Comment: The session key will not create a new or different session but just change where the auth data is stored withing the current session.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This will prevent the two apps' Authentication to interfere. Creating an entirely different session is my second solution.

Comment: Your first solution did the trick! I did: AuthComponent::$sessionKey = 'Auth.MyCustomModel'

Comment: How to use session key in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar issue which is why I've started a bounty on this question. Basically I have a public facing part of the application which lets users login from one table and an administrative part of the application which lets admins login using a different table. My AppController looks something like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'autoRedirect' => false,
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'User'
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'overview'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'loggedout')
    )
);
```

and I have another AdminController where I have this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'CustomForm' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin'
            )
        ),
        'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'login'),
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admin', 'action' => 'index'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
    )
);
```

But as mentioned in this question, sessions from the two don't get along and overwrite each other. What's the best way to overcome this?

Comment: I'm glad you raised a bounty. I learned something extra too while implementing this: setting scope in `Auth` in `AppController` creates problem with multiple logins. `'scope' => array('User.delete_status' => 0)` in `AppController` was not overwritten with `'scope' => array('Customer.delete_status' => 0)` in `CustomersController`. Instead, It got appended in the SQL query used by Cake like `.. WHERE User.delete_status=0 AND Customer.delete_status=0`. I had to move that bit into UsersController from AppController (like you have `Auth` in respective controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Model/Datasource/Session/DatabaseSession.php session handler with something like MyDatabaseSession and overwrite the write and read methods. Maybe simply copy the existing code of both methods and add something like

'app_id' => Configure::read('App.appId')

to the read() conditions and do the same in the write method. And do not forget to add the field to your session database schema and to [configure the session to use your handler](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/sessions.html#built-in-session-handlers-configuration).

```
<?php
App::uses('DatabaseSession', 'Model/Datasource/Session');
class ExtendedDatabaseSession extends DatabaseSession  {

    public function read($id) {
        $row = $this->_model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'app_id' => Configure::read('App.appId'),
                    $this->_model->primaryKey => $id)));

        if (empty($row[$this->_model->alias]['data'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $row[$this->_model->alias]['data'];
    }

    public function write($id, $data) {
        if (!$id) {
            return false;
        }
        $expires = time() + $this->_timeout;
        $record = compact('id', 'data', 'expires');
        $record[$this->_model->primaryKey] = $id;
        $record['app_id'] = Configure::read('App.appId');
        return $this->_model->save($record);
    }
}
```

I do not know your app, so were you write the app id to the config data is up to you, bootstrap or beforeFilter() maybe. You should add it before the session gets initialized I think or you'll need to re-init the session or something. I leave it up to you to look the right point up. :)