# multiple login in cakephp 3

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.4

I have to create on seperate login screen for user vendor type. Under the Appcontroller I have added

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event){

    $this->Auth->allow(['login', 'logout','vendor_login','vendor_logout']);

}

    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => [
                    'Acl.Actions' => ['actionPath' => 'controllers/']
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'Pages',
                    'action' => 'display',
                    'home'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login'
            ],  
            'vendorLoginAction' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'vendorLogin'
            ],
            'vendorLoginRedirect' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'BoldNumberRequest',
                    'action' => 'index',
                    'home'
            ],
            'vendorLogoutRedirect' => [
                    'plugin' => false,
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'vendorLogout'
            ],
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => [
                    'controller' => 'Pages',
                    'action' => 'display',
                    'prefix' => false
            ],
            'authError' => 'You are not authorized to access that location.',
            'flash' => [
                    'element' => 'error'
            ]
    ]);
```

vendorLogin function and vendor_login.ctp has been created for users.
In the route.php file i have added

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $vendorroutes) {
    $vendorroutes->setExtensions(['json', 'xml','pdf']);
    $vendorroutes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'vendorLogin']);
    $vendorroutes->connect('/boldnumberrequest/*', ['controller' => 'BoldNumberRequest', 'action' => 'index-vendor']);

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
Router::prefix('vendorLogin', function ($vendorroutes) {
    $vendorroutes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

Vendor login screen is coming but after login it should redirect to 
 http://localhost/polymer_erp/bold-number-request/index but it's redirecting to http://localhost/polymer_erp/pages/home that is default for other login user.
Is this procedure is correct and how can i change the default redirect after login.?

Comment: What you wrote there is not actually correct. You can have only ONE `loginAction` configured for the AuthComponent. So that code is not valid as far as CakePHP goes.

And "user vendor type" does not say much. Rewrite the question to better explain your use case. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: check out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352326/cakephp-3-login-as-wtih-multiple-auth-sessions